# Xamarin webview Android SSL error untrusted - how to add trusted certificate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have SSL error untrusted on my Xamarin application on adroid app (iOS works good). I need to use Webview.

I follow this instructions for httpclient : https://thomasbandt.com/certificate-and-public-key-pinning-with-xamarin . I need to set TrustManagerFactory, KeyManagerFactory and KeyStore, but in WebViewRenderer and WebViewClient I can not find option to add my certificates as trusted. I dont want to compare certificates in OnReceivedSslError override method, because certificate that come in this method is the final certificate (that will expire up to one year). I want to add my root and intermediate certificates to list of trusted certificates before checking certificate method in webview will be called.

ExportRenderer:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebViewRenderer
    {
        private TrustManagerFactory _trustManagerFactory;
        private KeyManagerFactory _keyManagerFactory;
        private KeyStore _keyStore;

        public CustomWebView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
                _trustManagerFactory = CertificateHelper.TrustManagerFactory;
                _keyManagerFactory = CertificateHelper.KeyManagerFactory;
                _keyStore = CertificateHelper.KeyStore;
                Control.SetWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to set TrustManagerFactory, KeyManagerFactory and KeyStore here?

Comment: You could  make HttpsURLConnection to trust a specific set of CAs. Please check the suggestions in native android. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa

Comment: I have checked this path, but I see no option how to get the core mechanism of webview or webview client to modify SSL factory or override any method. The second thing is that, this solution executes Load(null, null) for initializing and is clearing all CA that are trusted by default, so only custom certificate that I add will be trusted. In other words, going this way, if I add no certificates then all https connection will be untrusted. That is not what I want. Third thing - even if I modify SSL Factory of urlconnection, I only change object, that is not referenced to webview, that I want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found working solution. In my case adding end-user certificate or intermediate certificate, (separately or together), makes everything working. End-user cert is short term so I advice to add long term intermediate certificate.

Add:
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to manifest in application section.

Add new xml file (build action AndroidResource) to Resources -> xml -> network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config>
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="@raw/untrusted_ca"/>
      <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Name of certificate should consist of only lower case letters, numbers and underscore.

Add certificate (build action: AndroidResource) in: Resources -> raw -> untrusted_ca.pem

Now android webview trusts server on application level so no more ssl error occurs, when connecting to particular server.